# A Little Homework on Homework

Tags: discussion, homework

A recent "Do my homework for me" question on SO got me thinking: are there sites out there where people are recommending SO as a place where you can get other people to do your work for you? A bit of [searching with Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20do%20%22your%20homework%22%20-site:stackoverflow.com%20-site:stackoverflow.uservoice.com%20-site:codinghorror.com%20-site:joelonsoftware.com%20-site:brentozar.com%20-site:stackoverflow.fogbugz.com%20-site:www.alexa.com%20-%22usage%20statistics%22&first=51&FORM=PORE) got me the answer.

I found quite a number of references to SO in the context of homework, but none were what I was afraid of. Still, I thought I'd mention them in case someone else here appreciates the time I wasted on this. ;-)  Among other things, I found:

- [Psychic IRC Support In 10 Easy Steps](https://web.archive.org/web/20101003065637/http://www.muhuk.com:80/2009/06/psychic-irc-support-in-10-easy-steps/):

> Google your question. If your question
> is generic enough there is probably a
> blog post about it somewhere.
> StackOverflow has quite an impressive
> repertoire of Django related questions
> as well. In fact I suggest you to use
> SO for your non-trivial questions.

- [E6998 Summer 2009, Homework 4, "User Interfaces and Unit Testing", "Required Reading"](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecarlosrene/e6998/Hmwk4.html):

> Read [Is Unit Testing worth the Effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299/is-unit-testing-worth-the-effort/67500#67500)  at StackOverflow http://www.stackoverflow.com/.

- Blog post, "[Little updates here and there](https://balsamiq.com/company/news/2008/09/19/little-updates-here-and-there/)", "Feature Improvements"

> This was definitely NOT fun, look I even resorted to [asking advice on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88339/which-is-better-shipping-a-buggy-feature-or-not-shipping-the-feature-at-all)! (*)

- Finally, from Planeta Debian Brasil, on 14/07/2009, there's [João Eriberto Mota Filho](https://eriberto.pro.br/blog/), "**[DRBD com discos de 1 TB](https://eriberto.pro.br/blog/2009/07/14/drbd-com-discos-de-1-tb/)**":

Bem, o problema parece claro: **vmalloc() failed**. É o seguinte (resumo): o kernel pode alocar espaço para uso na memória física ou na virtual. Para a memória física ele usa kmalloc. Para memória virtual (RAM + swap) ele usa vmalloc. A literatura especializada diz que é raro usar vmalloc. No entanto, encontrei isto:

> kmalloc is limited in the size of buffer it can provide: 128 KBytes. If you need a really big buffer, you have to use vmalloc or some other mechanism like reserving high memory at boot.

> Fonte: STACK OVERFLOW. **What is the difference between vmalloc and kmalloc?**. Disponível em [What is the difference between vmalloc and kmalloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc). Acesso em 14 jul. 09.

Bottom line, I found the exact opposite of what I was looking for, which in this case, is a good thing.

---

(*) That's "[Which is better: shipping a buggy feature or not shipping the feature at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88339/which-is-better-shipping-a-buggy-feature-or-not-shipping-the-feature-at-all)", so you don't have to look it up.

---

Here's a little irony. I didn't realize I needed to include a "discussion" tag, so the question was rejected. When I added the tag and submitted again, I got the CAPTCHA screen. My words were "**Hum searched**".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Frankly, I'm convinced that there are consulting companies out there hiring people fresh out of bottom-tier colleges at rock-bottom prices, selling them as seasoned experts, and then handing them assignments along with a list of web forums.

Comment: I agree. At least 10% of the questions I answer at http://forums.asp.net/28.aspx are, in effect, "I've just been given the task of writing a web service. What's a web service?" And the fact that so many of these questions come from India unfairly stigmatizes Indians. I've worked with a _lot_ of great Indian developers, but this lot (or their managers, who won't pay for any training) are making a bad name for all of them.